# my "lisp-pl language" throwing mistakes

Tags: lisp

Cheers!!! i have a question about a function contract that i need to write in the pl language (a lisp contribution ) the contract suppose to have a (list of type A)(list of type b) and return a list of lists (type A B)  simultaneously  . this is what i got so far but it doesn't work :

```
(: zip2 : (All (A B) (Listof A) (Listof B) -> (Listof (list A B))))
(define (zip2 listA listB)
  (cond [(null? listA) (list (null null))]
        [else (list ((car listA) (car listB)))])
  (zip2 ((rest listA) (rest listB))))

(equal? (list (list 1 'a) (list 2 'b) (list 3 'c)) (zip2 (list 1 2 3) (list 'a 'b 'c)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (zip2 listA listB)
 (cond [(null? listA) null]
       [else (cons (list (car listA) (car listB))
                   (zip2 (rest listA) (rest listB)))]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest approach is just to use mapping.  [Since you are using `define` I'll assume you are using Scheme].

```
(define (zip A B) (map list A B))
```

If you can't use `map`, then here is a tail-recursive algorithm:

```
(define (zip A B)
  (let zipping ((a A) (b B) (rslt '())
    (if (or (null? a) (null? b))
        (reverse rslt)
        (zipping (cdr a) (cdr b)
                 (cons (list (car a) (car b)) rslt)))))
```